# How to auto insert data into database using the values from another table?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.
this is the incomes table

```
income_id   date_income   total_amount
   1        2022-05-22       14
   2        2022-05-22       15
   3        2022-05-21       20
   4        2022-05-21       25
```

and this is the total_income table

```
total_inc_id   income_id  date_income  total total_income_amount
     1             1      2022-05-22     2           29
```

However I want to count rows with the same date from table1 and store inside table 2 like above automatically whenever i add income. How can i achieve this?

Comment: If table 2 (total_income) computes from table 1, then what is the purpose of table 2?

Comment: What's `income_id` doing in `total_income` table? If `incomes` is a heavily transacted table, you don't want triggers but a `daily-cron-script` to update `total_income`.

Comment: @mardubbles likely for reporting/statistics purposes.

Comment: If you can generate the totals from the `incomes` table, dont store them in another table. If you do they will almost always be wrong. Instead run the query that gets the days total income

Comment: well actually total_income in first table which will calculate the total of specific products and total_income_amount is the combination of all incomes by using the same date.

Comment: Ideally you'd use a COUNT for your total and a SUM for your total_income_amount along with a GROUP BY. I don't know why you have income_id in your total_income table since the income_id would change, unless this is supposed to be a comma separated list, which wouldn't make sense either. The total_inc_id wouldn't make much sense either then because date_income would basically turn into your primary key. Then you'd want to INSERT/UPDATE to keep data up-to-date and set up a cronjob. Keep in mind edge cases such as when there's 0 income.